# custom pager for knockout arrayBinding

Tags: knockout.js, controls, customization, pager

i need to make a custom pager like [<] 1 2 3 4 ... > for a knockout binding array with 5 items. The items are in an article cuote .

I already tried with some examples aviables on internet, but i'm new in this matters so i didn't  solve the issue.

Can someone tell me how i can do this?
 greetings comunity!

Comment: looking for pagination kind of thing here ?

Comment: kind of datapager in asp.net

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/remcoros/ko.pager/wiki?

Comment: but, how I put this pager with my result array?, and  I have another problem, I have filters working over my observable array so, how can I put it together in a single result? I hope someone help me, I really need this thing working quickly. r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [this example](http://remcoros.github.io/ko.pager/example.html) to make my custom pagination. Thanx @MrGenius for your help.

Other references:

[Knockout template to create pagination UI / links similar to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047128/knockout-template-to-create-pagination-ui-links-similar-to-stackoverflow)